# How to move certain cells down in UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

I would like to move certain `UICollectionViewCell`s down by a fixed height. I tried overriding `-layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` and updating the `center` of some `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` in the array returned by `[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect]`, but somehow some cells went missing that way. Do I need to override something else?

[image]

Comment: could you solve it? tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this delegate method of UICollectionView you can change the frame for a specific cell :

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score -1):

Try implementing this delegate. It works for me:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.item == ....)
   {
      return newSize;
   }
   else
      return oldSize;
}
```

if you want this move to increase the height of cell be animated, you can call this delegate by

```
[_yourCollectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
```

So you can refresh your cell when some action is triggered.